# Issue with Entity Framework 6 & Sqlite. Any() query fails but Contains() query is working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

**Tools being used:**

1. Entity Framework 6.0
2. System.Data.Sqlite 1.0.98 Package [Latest Stable Build]

**Problem:**
Suppose the Code block given Below:

```
using(var dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
{
var hugeDataListObj= dbContext.Table1.Select(x=>x.Field1).ToList();
//Do other Stuff here with hugeDataListObj.

// The Below query will fail for Parser Stack overflow.
var requiredResultObj = dbContext.Table2.Where(x=>hugeDataList.Any(y=> y==x.Field1)).ToList(); 


//but The code given below works out well.
var requiredResultObj = dbContext.Table2.Where(x=>hugeDataList.Contains(x.Field1)).ToList(); 

/* Below given is the Detailed Exception.*/
 "InnerException": {
            "ExceptionType": "SQLiteException",
            "ExceptionMessage": "SQL logic error or missing database\r\nparser stack overflow",
            "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String& strRemain)\r\n   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()\r\n   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index)\r\n   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()\r\n   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)\r\n   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)",
            "Data": {},
            "ErrorCode": "-2147467259",
            "Source": "System.Data.SQLite",
            "HelpLink": null,
            "InnerException": null
        }
}
```

I have looked at the Query of Any and Contains. Both have a Huge difference. 
But then What i am confused about is that is Any() has got a Performance issue ? Or is this is Case Specific?

Comment: What is the type of `Field1`?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck : I have checked the same with Integer , Long, & String. All of do create a Problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first statement `var hugeDataListObj= dbContext.Table1.Select(x=>x.Field1).ToList();` is using `ToList()`, will evaluate the query and create a List<> of primitives in memory.

Your 2nd statement(s) use this list to build a SQL statement. It's no wonder that your EF providers are having trouble with this - it's probably attempting to build and execute a SQL statement that has a clause like `IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'...` which contains thousands of values.

These queries both use the same dbContext. Consider combining the queries into one before execution, which will cause the join to happen in the database.

Better still, because there are conceptual links between these two tables, you can create navigation properties in the entities, which makes it much easier to create EF/Linq queries around these objects. Consult the EF documentation on how to do this.